# 配列から重複なしで2つずつの要素を取り出し、新たな配列に格納したい。2 つない場合は、切り捨て

Tags: php

元データ配列
要素数19

```
$hogeAry = ['111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','77777','888888','9999999','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818','1911919'];
```

ランダム並べ替えした結果の例

```
$hogeAry = ['1911919','111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','77777','888888','9999999','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818'];
```

今回、取得したい結果。
重複しないよう、2 つずつ新しい配列へ格納

```
$ary=[['1911919','111111'],['222222','333333'],['444444','555555'],['666666','77777'],['888888','9999999'],['101010','111111'],['121212','131313'],['141414','151515'],['161616','171717']];
```

試したコード1(結果が重複することがある)

```
$hogeAry= ['111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','77777','888888','9999999','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818','1911919'];
shuffle($hogeAry);
$ary=[];
$loopNum=intval(count($hogeAry)/2);//9
for ($i=0;$i<$loopNum;$i++) {
  $ary[$i][0]=$hogeAry[$i];
  $ary[$i][1]=$hogeAry[$i+1];
}
print_r($ary);
```

試したコード2(取得件数が少ない)

```
$hogeAry= ['111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','77777','888888','9999999','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818','1911919'];
shuffle($hogeAry);
$ary=[];
$loopNum=intval(count($hogeAry)/2);//9
for ($i=0;$i<$loopNum;$i=$i+2) {
  $ary[$i][0]=$hogeAry[$i];
  $ary[$i][1]=$hogeAry[$i+1];
}
print_r($ary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試したコード1は配列のインデックスに問題があり、コード2はループ回数に問題があります。
下記のように`for`文を書き換えると取得したい結果が得られます。

```
// ランダム並べ替えした結果の例をそのまま流用
$hogeAry = ['1911919','111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','77777','888888','9999999','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818'];
$ary = [];

$loopNum = intval(count($hogeAry) / 2); // 9
for ($i = 0; $i < $loopNum; $i++) {
    $ary[] = [$hogeAry[$i * 2], $hogeAry[$i * 2 + 1]];
}

print_r($ary);
```

Comment: 期待した通り動作しました

Answer (score 2):

2 個ずつ分けたいだけなら array_chunk() を使うと良いと思います

参考: https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.array-chunk.php

ただし，これだけだと「2つない場合は切り捨て」が実現できず最後の Chunk は要素1の配列になるため，あまりが出るかどうかは先に考えておくと良いと思います．

```php
$inputs = ['111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','77777','888888','9999999','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818','1911919'];
shuffle($inputs);

// 今回は 2 個ずつに分けます
$chunkSize = 2;

// 2 個ずつに分けたときにあまりが出るかどうか
$hasRemainder = count($inputs) % $chunkSize !== 0;

$outputs = array_chunk($inputs, $chunkSize);

// 端数が出るときだけ末尾の要素を削除
if ($hasRemainder) {
    array_pop($outputs);
}


print_r($outputs);
```

Comment: array_chunk()、こんな標準関数があるのですね。初めて知りました。参考になりました